# What are the stages in a 5-stage clos network?

Tags: topology

A [3-stage clos topology](https://infohub.delltechnologies.com/l/enterprise-sonic-distribution-by-dell-technologies-layer-3-fabric/fabric-topologies-31) makes sense to me. You have servers->leaves->spines. However you see at the bottom of that same page it has a "Clos three-tier network with superspines". That appears to me to be the same as this [5-stage clos topology](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/apstra4.0/apstra-user-guide/topics/topic-map/5-stage-clos.html) where you have endpoint->leaf->spine->superspine.

What I don't understand is why that's called a 5-stage topology. It looks like there are only four stages. Where does the 5th stage come from?

Answer (score 3):

Got it figured out.

The stages include the return path and do not include the endpoint. So the path is
leaf->spine->superspine->spine->leaf for a total of 5 hops.

Comment: It's pretty much the same as Cisco's 3-tier [hierarchical network design](https://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=2202410&seqNum=4). The term *[Clos network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clos_network)* is actually obsolete as it refers to a multistage design in *circuit* switching. With three stages, those are *ingress - mixing - egress*.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I hear this term often from multiple sources and major network equipment providers still use it. https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/apstra4.0/apstra-user-guide/topics/topic-map/5-stage-clos.html